# If I encrypt my partition can my data that wasn't encrypted be still recovered?

Tags: windows, hard-drive, encryption

Let's assume a scenario:

1. I have a file on a partition in Windows 8 NTFS that isn't encrypted with BitLocker.
2. I create a file on said partition.
3. I delete the file.
4. I encrypt the partition with BitLocker.

Can the file be still recovered with any recovering software or any trace of it is also encrypted ?

Comment: Bitlocker encrypts freespace also.  That should answer your question.

Comment: @Ramhound, it doesn't always encrypt free space.  You can choose to skip that during the setup.

Comment: Who wouldn't encrypt free space in a situation like this?  **My comment is still valid.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is that this is configurable.  What happens depends on the selections you make during the initial setup.

During the wizard that runs you will see a page labeled `Choose how much of your drive to encrypt`.  You have two choices `Encrypt used space only`, and `Encrypt entire drive`.  If you currently has data on it tha needs to be protected, then you should almost certainly choose **Encrypt entire drive**.  You should almost never choose the Encrypt used space only option, unless this is a brand new installation of Windows with no data on it at all.

If you have a drive with bitlocker setup on it, and you don't recall what options were used during the initial setup, then you can use a command like [sdelete](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897443.aspx) to securely wipe the free space after the fact.

[image: bitlocker free space wipe]

Technet article about speed improvements from not wiping free space:  http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/jj983729.aspx